# Limit point of a sequence and range

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Anyone can please give some examples where limit point of the sequence is different from limit point of range of that sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$. The limit point of that sequence is $0$, but the since the range of the sequence $[-\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ is continuous, every point in the range is a limit point.

Here I take it that your definition of "limit point" is any point $L$ with all its open neighborhood ("interval around the point") having points in that neighborhood other than $L$ itself.

Comment: Why is the range of the sequence continuous?  It's only countable, isn't it?  e.g. there're no points between -1 and -1/3.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but for future reference, here's a simple example: Let 
$$p_n\triangleq\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1, & n\le 5 \\ 2, & n>5 \end{array}\right.$$

Then '$2$' is the limit and the only limit point of the sequence $\{p_n\}$.  But the range of the sequence is a finite set $\{1,2\}$, so it clearly has no limit points.